# Is image generation not existent before generative adversarial networks?

Tags: generative-adversarial-networks, generative-model, history, image-generation

Although the GAN is widely used due to its capability, there were generative models before the GAN which are based on probabilistic graphical models such as Bayesian networks, Markov networks, etc.

It is now a well-known fact that GANs are excelling at image generation tasks. But I am not sure whether the generative models that were invented before GANs were used for image generation or not.

Is it true that other generative models were used for image **generation** before the proposal of the GAN in 2014?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "image generation" and whether you have any constraints on the type of model used? If the question is open enough then I would not be surprised to find automated image generation that predates deep neural networks, or any neural networks or even computers

Comment: @NeilSlater I mean image generation using AI generative models  that exist before GAN.

Comment: How about autoencoders?

Comment: @user253751 It is identity function right? It may come under reconstruction rather than generation, but if it can able to generate diverse, then yeah.

Comment: An autoencoder is trying to simulate an identity function, but you can also delete the first half, inject random values into the bottleneck layer, and see what you get.

Comment: @user253751 Can it generate novel and realistic images?

Comment: @hanugm: Yes. In fact there is a minor change to autoencoders called variational autoencoders (VAEs) and they can be used in many similar situations as GANs, although they have different strengths and weaknesses. There is even a VAE-GAN architecture that combines both approaches

Comment: You can also use any image classifier as a generator by optimizing the image to maximize the score of a particular class. This was called Deep Dream. In this case you need a starting image, which could be plain grey or black or white, but you can also start from other images.